# I learn Spanish by reading short stories

Tags: traducción

I want to say in Spanish :

> I learn Spanish by reading short stories.

My attempt:

> Aprendo español leyendo cuentos.

Is my translation correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Completely correct.

Comment: It's just perfect like that.

Comment: perfect! Muy bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La traducción es aceptable en un sentido amplio, pero sería más apropiado traducir como

> Aprendo español leyendo cuentos cortos

Para así hacer referencia al modificador "short" que aparece en la frase original.

Comment: No es así, el cuento como género literario se conoce en inglés como _short story_; por lo tanto, es innecesario traducir el "short".

Comment: Existen cuentos cortos y cuentos largos. [Ver diferencia](http://www.diferencia-entre.com/diferencia-entre-cuento-y-novela/).  Si uno quiere aclarar puede decir **cortos**. Entiendo que esta pregunta no merecía una respuesta porque en los comentarios se aclaró que la traducción era correcta. Lo que no entiendo es el voto negativo a esta respuesta.

Comment: @DGaleano El enlace explica la diferencia entre cuento y novela, no entre "cuento corto" y "cuento largo". _Short story_ se traduce como _cuento_, luego "short" no es un modificador, por ello la respuesta es incorrecta o, al menos, desorientadora.

Comment: @JMVanPelt Permitirme explicar. Lo que quise decir en mi comentario anterior y el enlace explica es que un cuento no esta limitado en extensión, o sea que decir simplemente "cuento" no implica automáticamente que sea corto.
Decir "leo cuentos" significa que leo indistintamente los largos y los cortos, por lo tanto si quiero especificar que solo leo los cortos, lo debo decir explícitamente y no lo puedo dejar implícito. De ahí mi voto positivo.

Comment: @DGaleano Bien, comprendo y estoy de acuerdo con que es así en español. Por el contrario, hasta donde yo sé, _short story_ en inglés no implica que estés leyendo un cuento corto sino meramente un cuento. De hecho, por lo que he visto buscando en internet, un cuento corto sería una _short short story_ y un cuento largo, una _long short story_.

Comment: -1 I agree with JMVanPelt. `Cuento` is implicitly a short story already. It is redundant to say cuentos cortos.